# Generating Python classes for SQLite database

Tags: windows, gratis, python, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite 3 database and I need to write Python code that deals with it, basically the typical CRUD operations as an object oriented wrapper around the database. I find myself writing stupid SQL queries like `SELECT this FROM there;` and create a list of objects of a certain type.

The task feels so stupid and repetitive that I think someone must have written a code generator or something to do this more reliably than I ever could.

Such a generator or library shall be free of cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) helped me reduce the code by ~50%.

And then I found that Peewee comes with a tool called [Pwiz](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#pwiz), which generates Python code from the database, which helped a lot, because that way I only need to be able to read the code and adapt it. I learn a lot while reading the generated code. That's great.

I ran the following code in a Pycharm terminal:

```
python -m pwiz -e sqlite my.db > my_db_model.py
```

Code generated (excerpt):

```
class Weeklytask(BaseModel):
    id = AutoField(column_name='ID', null=True)
    task_markdown = CharField(column_name='TaskMarkdown', null=True)
    year_of_study = IntegerField(column_name='YearOfStudy', null=True)

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'weeklytask'
```

When you use it, maybe it's good to know:

- You can't write the query 
  `Assignments.select().where(Assignments.completed is None)` 
  but use 
  `Assignments.select().where(Assignments.completed.is_null(True))`
  instead.